# How to use a IF statement in devexpress report's filtering string?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have created a Devexpress xtrareport , and I have set it's data source to a dataset which contain MyData table.  And I want to achieve something like in the below picture ,
Can someone tell me how to achieve this behavior ?

```
-------------------------
      MY Data Table
-------------------------
 Active |  Name  | Age 
------------------------
 True   | Okas   | 1 
 True   | Kaos   | 2 
 False  | Kas    | 3
```

[image]

Comment: I see you have "MY Data Table" at the top. Are you referring to that? If so then look at XtraReport Bands, Header and Footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search on internet I found that to use `IReport.ParametersRequestSubmit` to dynamically change the `XtraReport.FilterString` property in code.
This is the way to solve this problem